# Read content of textfile between start- and endmarkers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a program that reads a textfile and outputs a result based on a set of conditions. Within the file itself, there is a lot of irrelevant information to ignore.

I used slicing to set guidelines for where I wanted the program to look. However, this prevents the code from being relevant for other texts with different formatting.

I've placed prompts like * START * and * FINISH * within each file to illustrate where I wish the program to begin and conclude its search.

This is where I'm at right now...

```
for line in open('filename.txt'):
    if line.startswith('* START'):
        #do stuff

    if line.endswith('* FINISH'):
        #do stuff
```

Excuse my ignorance, but I'm unsure as to how I achieve the same results as slicing with this method.

```
slicing = list[5:-5]
```

Would appreciate any pointers - Cheers!

Comment: did you get everything to work?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I tried a few different things to no avail. I can show you what I have if you like?

Comment: you could tell me what problems you are facing when trying to use the code from my answer. It is working fine for me. Or you can edit your attempts into your question so others can give more specific help.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file line by line until you reach the start marker, and then do something until you reach the endmarker. For example:

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while not line.startswith('* START'):
        line = f.readline()
    while not line.endswith('* FINISH *\n'):
        # add code to do something with the line here
        # e.g. print it, store it to a list, ...
        line = f.readline()
    # do something to the line ending with '* FINISH *\n' here
```

Comment: I understand that but I'm trying to make it so it ignores all the other text and only looks at what is between the START and FINISH.

Comment: The example program reads in lines and ignores them until it finds the start-marker. Then it continues to read lines until it finds the end-marker and ignores the lines after that. If that's not what you want please explain what you want a bit more.

Comment: @Androx no problem. Maybe you should add some print(line) statements and run the code on a small sample file to see what it does. If you need something else / something additional just tell me.